# Why the need for XmlNamespaceManager when parsing XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So when I was getting a null value using selectSingleNode, I found that I needed to declare a namespace because I was using the xmlns attribute.  My question is why I need to use a prefix when parsing the xml, if I don't use the prefix in the xml file itself?

The reason I have the xmlns attribute, is because the receiving end of my xml output requires it.  I would rather read it in from the base xml than have it hardcoded in the program.

This is the code that works

```
xmlns = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlTemplate.NameTable)
xmlns.AddNamespace("dc", ns)
```

I tried doing this - doesn't work

```
xmlns = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlTemplate.NameTable)
xmlns.AddNamespace(String.Empty, ns)
```

In short, is there any way to get rid of the "dc" prefix?

Comment: What's the XML you are parsing look like?

Comment: Below, chris assumed correctly.  Boils down to something like "<xml xmlns="http://www.exmaple.com/"><node/></xml>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just one of those "that's the way they built it" kind of things. According to [MSDN (XPath Queries with Namespaced Mapped Prefixes)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa735774%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The XmlNamespaceManager allows adding
>   default namespaces by using an empty
>   string as the prefix. However, XPath
>   treats the empty prefix as the null
>   namespace. In other words, only
>   prefixes mapped to namespaces can be
>   used in XPath queries. If you want to
>   use the default namespace from an XML
>   document in the XPath expression, then
>   you need to define a prefix for it.

And also from [MSDN (XmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx):

> If the XmlNamespaceManager will be
>   used for resolving namespaces in an
>   XML Path Language (XPath) expression,
>   a prefix must be specified. If an
>   XPath expression does not include a
>   prefix, it is assumed that the
>   namespace Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI) is the empty namespace

**EDIT**

And I'm assuming your code is something like:

```vb
Dim S = "<xml xmlns=""http://www.exmaple.com/""><node/></xml>"

Dim X As New Xml.XmlDocument()

X.LoadXml(S)
Dim NS As New Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(X.NameTable)
NS.AddNamespace("dc", "http://www.exmaple.com/")

''//Will not work
Dim N1 = X.SelectSingleNode("//xml/node", NS)
If N1 Is Nothing Then
    Trace.WriteLine("Node not found")
Else
    Trace.WriteLine("Node found")
End If

''//Works
Dim N2 = X.SelectSingleNode("//dc:xml/dc:node", NS)
If N2 Is Nothing Then
    Trace.WriteLine("Node not found")
Else
    Trace.WriteLine("Node found")
End If
```

Comment: Alright - so then the ideal situation would be that the receiving party would simply read the xml and add the namespace as they need it?  That way I don't have to prefix everything with a hardcoded "dc:".  If that is the case, then I am satisfied.  Btw, your assumption in my code is exactly correct.

Comment: Do you need the namespace in there? Can you just remove it?

Comment: I'll try to explain it better: I have an xml which I read -> add to the content -> forward it to another process which receives it.  Instead of hardcoding the xmlns in the code, I wanted it to just pre-exist in the xml.  The reason for that being, anything changed in this 'template' per say, should not be changed in the code.  It seems though that the process receiving the xml (which relies on the xmlns) should be the one adding the namespace, and not me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the namespace from the incoming XML instead of having to hardcode it by doing:

```
NS.AddNamespace("dc",X.DocumentElement.Attributes("xmlns").InnerText)
```